# In react-native the variable is getting rendered but the value is not getting passed to the child screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

**New to React/React-Native**
After authentication the Home page opens, it has two tabs "Payment" and "Notice". I want to access the user email and location in payment tab. The email is successfully getting rendered in the first Text section of the Home page. But the value is not getting passed in the payment tab. Also similar problem is seen with the location object. I know I am missing something fundamental about the render sequence but I don't know what to search for.

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { useAuthentication } from '../utils/hooks/useAuthentication';
import { signOut, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const auth = getAuth();

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function NoticeTab({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notice Tab</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function PaymentTab({ navigation, route }) {
  const { email, location } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{email}</Text>
      <Text> {location ? location.coords.latitude.toString() : "Waiting for coordinates"}</Text>
      <Text> {location?.coords.longitude.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const { user } = useAuthentication();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user?.email);

  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setEmail(user?.email);
    (async () => {
      console.log("useEffect");

      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);

    })();
  }, [user?.email, location]);

  return(
      <View style={{ flex: 10 }}>
        <Text>Welcome {user?.email}</Text>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Notice" component={NoticeTab} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Payment" component={PaymentTab} initialParams={{ email: email, location: location }} navigation={navigation}} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </View>
);
}
```

and the `useAuthentication` hook looks like the following

```
import React from 'react';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth';

const auth = getAuth();

export function useAuthentication() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeFromAuthStatuChanged = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        setUser(undefined);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribeFromAuthStatuChanged;
  }, []);

  return {
    user
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React-Native, but I'll try to explain something anyway.

Usually when I'm working with some kind of "Navigators", like TabNavigator, I never put any application logic in the navigator itself. If you really need a static "top bar" that says in all screens "Hello, this@mymail.com!" it's ok, but I think the problem are those "initial parameters".

If you want a component to know about something, and this "something" can be retrieved without passing it, go for it. Just let the `PaymentTab` object re-declare all the:

```
function PaymentTab({ navigation, route }) {
  const { user } = useAuthentication();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user?.email);
  ...
}
```

And remember that React will get angry (but will allow you anyway) when you're passing some non-serializable values as your params.

I can leave you this link I'm using as reference for React Native (you should find something also for "React"):
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/

*The problem with your app could be that at first render the app doesn't know the mail yet, since user could be undefined. In your TabNavigator the initial param you're passing is undefined and it's not getting updated, since it's only an INITIAL PARAM that was already set as undefined, even if the screen re-render.*